# Kivy widget out of expected boundaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm making custom touch handling for my widget. The way I have it set up is that the initial size of the widget is set and fixed, however, later, I change it dynamically depending on the contents. I turned that feature down for now to shorten the code, it doesn't affect the problem. I've noticed something strange when I clicked at a blank spot to the right of the widget and the touch was registered, so I added a canvas background to inspect. Apparently, the actual widget boundaries are set much bigger than what the actual widget instance is, and I don't really know what's causing this. Those widgets are positioned in a `FloatLayout`, but I never set `size_hints`, only sizes. Could that be the case? How do I shorten the widget boundaries to what they're supposed to be?

Here is the entire source code, the problem is most likely in the kv definition:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

global pr_msg_y
pr_msg_y = 5

Builder.load_string('''            
<ScrollView>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Message>:
    width: 500
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.3
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        height: self.height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: root.pos
                size: self.size

        TextInput:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
            id: msg
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            text: str(msg)
''')

class Message(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Message, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("Touch within {}".format(self))

class Chat(Screen):
    pass

class MessageInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MessageInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class ChatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        def msg_in(btn):
            global pr_msg_y
            inst = Message()
            inst.ids['msg'].text = "test" * 15
            inst.width = 456 # something random, the sizing should be dynamic
            inst.height = 40         
            for i in inst.walk():
                i.height = inst.height
                i.width = inst.width

            inst.y = sv1_main.height - 5 - pr_msg_y - inst.height
            msg_float.add_widget(inst)
            pr_msg_y += inst.height + 5

        Screens = ScreenManager(transition = NoTransition())
        chat = Chat(name = "main")        
        sv1_main = ScrollView(pos_hint = {"top":0.87, "center_x":0.5},
                              size_hint = (0.97, 0.65))
        msg_float = FloatLayout()

        bt1_main = Button(pos_hint = {"top":0.097, "center_x":0.951},
                          on_press = msg_in)

        Screens.add_widget(chat)
        chat.add_widget(sv1_main)
        sv1_main.add_widget(msg_float)
        chat.add_widget(bt1_main)

        return Screens

ChatApp().run()
```

Comment: Always use `size_hint = [None, None]` if you are not sure. And yes, it's caused because you didn't write it there(e.g. under Message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`size_hint` does "overwrite" `size`. By default `size_hint` is set to `1,1`, so if you only set size and you put the widget into a layout that recognizes size_hints, the widget will get the maximal available size.

Set `size_hint = None, None` to fix.